# Function with multiple parameters

Tags: excel, vba, function, arguments

I have a VBA function with multiple arguments, which I need to get from the excel sheet and not from a sub, how do I divide the inputs into the number of parameters i need for my function?

Ex:

```
Function func(a as double,b as double) as double
    'calculations
    'some return value
End Function
```

This is how I have been trying to get the values:

[image: This is how I have been trying to get the values]

Answer (score 4):

if you want to handle multiple arguments of which you don't know the number of, then use `ParamArray` argument

for instance, assuming `func()` should simply sum the arguments you pass it:

```
Function func(ParamArray args() As Variant) As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    For i = LBound(args) To UBound(args) '<--| loop through each passed argument
        If TypeName(args(i)) = "Range" Then '<--| if the current element is a Range
            For Each cell In args(i) '<--| loop through range cells
                func = func + cell.Value
            Next cell
        Else '<--| otherwise
            func = func + args(i) '<--| simply process the current argument value
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

Code:

```
Function TestFunction(a As Double, b As Double) As Double

   TestFunction = a + b

End Function
```

Excel Sheet:

```
=TestFunction(A1,B1)
```

Comment: Yes, however when I choose the cells in excel, and divide the parameters with a comma, I still get an error. The cell where I want the function to be in says that the value is wrong. What I want to know is how can I manually enter three excel cell values as parameters to a vba function.

Comment: My understanding of the comma and simicolon difference is that some language settings use one, while others use the other. For the problem you are encountering, I would need to know which equations you are using, however, cells are sometimes formatted as text or some alternative format. The other thing that sometimes goes wrong is a divide by zero situation. Have you stepped through the calculations with the debugger?