# Function to handle various conditions(arguments)

Tags: excel, vba

I have rows of data that I need to segregate based on different criteria. I am trying to write one function to capture all the conditions but not sure how to architect it. My first thought is using a case statement perhaps? That still repeats a lot of code.

```
Sub stackoverflow()
'first criteria is string
hold = "Yes"
arrTarget = populate(hold)
wsHold.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrTarget), UBound(arrTarget, 2)) = arrTarget

'second criteria is date
dueDate = InputBox("Enter cut off date for check run" & vbCrLf & "date entered is inclusive" & vbCrLf & "(any format works?)")
arrTarget = populate(dueDate)
wsNext.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrTarget), UBound(arrTarget, 2)) = arrTarget


End Sub

Function populate(arg As Variant) As Variant

Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim arrSource As Variant
Dim arrReturn As Variant

Set wsSource = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With wsSource

lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

arrSource = .Range("A2:L" & lastRow) 'store source range into source array

Select Case arg 'some puesdo code to follow
case string
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrSource)
        If arrSource(i, 9) = arg Then
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next

    ReDim arrReturn(1 To k, 1 To UBound(arrSource, 2))

    k = 0

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrSource)
        If arrSource(i, 9) = arg Then
            k = k + 1
            For j = 1 To UBound(arrSource, 2)
                arrReturn(k, j) = arrSource(i, j)
            Next
        End If
    Next

'if it's date, we want to test if greater than date
Case Date
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrSource)
        If DateValue(arrSource(i, 9)) > DateValue(arg) Then
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next

so on and so forth...

End With

populate = arrReturn

End Function
```

Basically, how can I manipulate `If arrSource(i, 9) = arg Then` based on condition? Sometimes I want `=`, sometimes `>`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441436/function-with-multiple-parameters) may help.

Comment: @MilesFett ah yes, I came across `paramarray` once when Tim Williams mentioned it... it was not light reading XD

Comment: @MilesFett nevermind, `typename` may be what I need, thanks! Edit: I still will repeat lots of code though?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's going to save a lot of typing, but if you want to manipulate a testing condition without having to rewrite it all the time, you could create a `Compare` function that takes the type of comparison as an argument.

You could have a new type that you define as follow at the top of the module

```
Enum ComparisonType
  vbEquality = 1
  vbBigger = 2
  vbSmaller = 4
End Enum
```

And then the function could look like this

```
Function Compare(ByVal lhs As Variant, ByVal rhs As Variant, ComparisonType As ComparisonType) As Boolean

    If ComparisonType = vbEquality Then

        If lhs = rhs Then
            Compare = True
        End If

    ElseIf ComparisonType = vbBigger Then

        If lhs > rhs Then
            Compare = True
        End If

    ElseIf ComparisonType = vbSmaller Then

        If lhs < rhs Then
            Compare = True
        End If

    End If

End Function
```

And since the different comparisons have a different values (powers of two in this case), you could use a method that calculates the type of comparison you want based on different conditions that are being combined into a single number.

Comment: `enum` is not a bad idea. I guess I could call a function within a function. Something worth exploring thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will not really get rid of the case thing until you decide to put everything in variants. but you can ease your life dramatically :)

```
     dim n1  as long 
     n1=  UBound(arrSource,1) 'dimension 1
     dim n2 as long 
     n2  UBound(arrSource,2) 'dimension '2

     For i = 1 to n1
     For j = 1 to n2

     var data=arrSource(i,j)


     'now you could convert everyting to string or variant 
      VT= VarType(data) 

                Select Case  VT

                    Case vbDouble

                         dim d as double 
                         d=cdbl(data)     'or 
                         dim v as variant 
                         v=data


                    Case vbString  '8

                    Case vbEmpty    '0

                    Case vbNull  '1

                    Case vbInteger    '2

                    Case vbLong    '3

                    Case vbSingle    '4

                    Case vbDouble  '5

                    Case vbCurrency  '6

                    Case vbDate  '7

                    Case vbObject    '9

                    Case vbError    '10

                    Case vbBoolean    '11

                    Case vbVariant    '12

                    Case vbDataObject    '13

                    Case vbDecimal    '14

                    Case vbByte    '15

                    Case Else

                End Select

     now do your calculations with the single data element
     'and convert it back if you want 
     Select Case  VT'w know already what was data before

                    Case vbDouble
                       data=cdbl(v)
                    Case vbString  '8

                    Case vbEmpty    '0

                    Case vbNull  '1

                    Case vbInteger    '2

                    Case vbLong    '3

                    Case vbSingle    '4

                    Case vbDouble  '5

                    Case vbCurrency  '6

                    Case vbDate  '7

                    Case vbObject    '9

                    Case vbError    '10

                    Case vbBoolean    '11

                    Case vbVariant    '12

                    Case vbDataObject    '13

                    Case vbDecimal    '14

                    Case vbByte    '15

                    Case Else

                End Select



     next
     next
```

And for sure both select trees you could develop to functions

```
          function convertback(data,vt) as variant
               select case(vt)
                    Case vbDouble

                       data=cdbl(v)

                    Case vbString  '8

                    Case vbEmpty    '0

                    Case vbNull  '1

                    Case vbInteger    '2

                    Case vbLong    '3

                    Case vbSingle    '4

                    Case vbDouble  '5

                    Case vbCurrency  '6

                    Case vbDate  '7

                    Case vbObject    '9

                    Case vbError    '10

                    Case vbBoolean    '11

                    Case vbVariant    '12

                    Case vbDataObject    '13

                    Case vbDecimal    '14

                    Case vbByte    '15

                    Case Else

                End Select
            convertback= data
            end function
```

Hope this helps a bit